# Installing RVM: Synchronization of the local ports tree failed doing rsync

Tags: ruby, synchronization, rvm, rsync, macports

I'm new to Ruby and working with the terminal. I installed the rvm, but I can't seem to be able to install Ruby 1.9.3. The problem seems to be with rsync and synching the ports tree. I have no idea what this means.

I tried looking up other solutions, but none of them are pertinent to rvm(that I could understand. They all just focused on autoupdated macports through itself). I also saw things about proxys, but I have no idea what I'd need to do if that was true. They all mainly focus on macports, and surround using words like "sudo" or -d, which I don't know how to do when just trying to install Ruby. Here is what I get:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p429.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Installing macports............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................Password:
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
DEBUG: Copying /Users/Elvis/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
receiving file list ... done
base.tar

sent 58 bytes  received 955032 bytes  272882.86 bytes/sec
total size is 3594240  speedup is 3.76
receiving file list ... done
base.tar.rmd160

sent 58 bytes  received 635 bytes  1386.00 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 0.74
DEBUG: successful verification with key /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem
DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp -xf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 installed,
DEBUG: Rebuilding and reinstalling MacPorts if needed
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after  rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done
ports.tar
WARNING: ports.tar failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).
rsync: read errors mapping "/tarballs/ports.tar" (in release): No data available (61)
ports.tar

sent 80 bytes  received 11948570 bytes  682780.00 bytes/sec
total size is 53186560  speedup is 4.45
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(1400) [generator=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after  rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 23
Error: Synchronization of the local ports tree failed doing rsync
DEBUG: Couldn't sync the ports tree: Synchronization of 1 source(s) failed
    while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /Users/Elvis/.rvm/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Couldn't sync the ports tree: Synchronization of 1 source(s) failed
Elviss-MacBook-Pro:~ Elvis$ ./port -d selfupdate
-bash: ./port: No such file or directory
```

I tried using some of the keywords/answers I saw online at the end, which explains the ./port line. I've installed command lines from xcode. Would installing homebrew help fix this problem? I'd appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make sure the following command runs properly

```
port selfupdate
```

and then try again

Comment: sweet that definitely helped me into the right direction @mpapis! Thanks a lot! For anyone else who has this problem in the future, this line worked for me: 
sudo port -d selfupdate

Comment: what does the `-d` flag do? how is it different from running without it?

Comment: the -d flag is for a more "verbose output." Running just port selfupdate gave me this error:
Error: /Users/Elvis/.rvm/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed

I think the sudo may have just done the job though!